# Magento 2 Catalog Search not showing correct results

Tags: magento2.3, catalogsearch, advanced-search, search-terms

Whenever I enter the keyword in the search bar and hit enter then the results are not related to that keyword.

For example, when i start typing madinah arabic there is a lot of results against that keyword in product search suggestions but when I hit enter it is giving totally different results in the Magento catalog search.

Product Search suggestions  :

[image]

Catalog Products Result :

[image]

Comment: Do you know the concept of Visibility?It determines if the product is visible in the catalog, and made available for search. Values:
Not Visible Individually — The product is not included in product listings, although it might be available as a variation of another product.
Catalog — The product appears in all catalog listings.
Search —The product is available for search operations.
Catalog, Search — The product is included in catalog listings and is also available for search.

Comment: Please check the visibility of Madinah Arablic reader book product and also check if product is in stock or out of stock

Comment: yes I checked the visibility of products and its set to catalog, search option.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the search type to '**Fulltext**' in '**System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search**' and then reindex the magento, check if this solves the problem.

Comment: there is no option of search type in catalog search

Comment: I'm using Magento 2.2.9, few months I go I used to see this option Search Type, but not any more after I updated my magento (composer update) same version 2.2.9. Not sure if it got removed. 

@AliSultanKhan since you have 2.3, do you have elastic search option?